# Are there any reserved NPM package names?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I tried to publish 2 packages to NPM with the substring "download" in the package names. Both times I get the http 400 error during the publishing process, no further explanation given.  The packages are scoped so no name conflicts...
Now im wondering if the word "download" is a reserved word.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/package-name-guidelines

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. Unfortunately I cant find any mentions of the term "download" in the whole docs. The only related info might be: 

"You will not buy, sell, or otherwise trade in user names, organization names, names for Packages, or any other names reserved on npm Services, for money or other compensation.". 

"[...] any other names reserved on npm Services" ...

Comment: I'm thinking more the part that says _"choose a name that is not spelled in a similar way to another package name, will not confuse others about authorship"_

Comment: The packages are scoped and there is no name conflict.

Comment: Ah - I'd contact npm then and ask them for clarification.

Comment: Did you tried to publish a package without `download` substring to see if it works?